# Xamarin Store Colors for ios and android

Tags: android, ios, colors

I want to store colors in a way that they can be used for both platforms.

I could create a class in the PCL or a shared project, but I am not finding a way to load a color from a xml file. Since we make xml files that are placed in the drawables they refer to colors like this way : @color/black

Is there a way to store the values of colours in a portable way for both platforms?

Comment: Do you have an example of such an XML file? Why don't you User a SQLite database?Reading an writing a Database table will be mich more efficient than reading and writing of an XML file. And you can put the whole Logic of the Database creation, access, etc. in a separate PCL.

Comment: <resources>
  <color name="test_white">#FFFFFF</color>
  <color name="test_black">#000000</color>
</resources>
This would be an example of the color xml file content.

plus this line has to work -> ContextCompat.GetColor(context, Resource.Color.test_black);